# How to efficiently generate only odd (or even) random numbers?

Tags: java, optimization, random

From looking at other questions regarding the generation of **only** even or odd numbers, I was curious as to what method would be the most efficient (in terms of speed).

For example, let's say that I wanted to generate many odd numbers that range from 1 (inclusive) to 1000 (exclusive); for each iteration, the method I would normally use is the following:

- Generate a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 500 (exclusive)
- Multiply by `2`
- Add `1`

Is there any better method?

Answer (score 4):

I happened to stumble upon this method today and I can't find any use of it on StackOverflow for generating only even or odd numbers.

This method takes advantage of the fact that, in binary, all even numbers (including `0`) have their least-significant bit set to `0` whereas all odd numbers have their least-significant bit set to `1`.

Therefore, to generate an odd number, we can simply generate a random number within the desired range and bitwise-or it with `1`:

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 1_000) | 1
```

With this method, if the generator selects an odd number, then it is left alone.  However, if an even number is selected, then bitwise-or'ing it with `1` essentially increments it.

Likewise, to generate even numbers between `2` (inclusive) and `1000` (exclusive), then we just need to clear the least-significant bit.  To do this, we can simply bitwise-and the value with `-2`:

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2, 1_000) & -2
```

With this method, if the generator selects an even number, then it is left alone.  However, if an odd number is selected, then bitwise-and'ing it with `-2` essentially decrements it.

These methods work perfectly fine with negative values, and `long` as well.

Here is a JMH benchmark comparing the two methods for generating an odd number between `1` (inclusive) and `1000` (exclusive):

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 20, time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(5)
public class MyBenchmark {

    private static final ThreadLocalRandom RANDOM = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int oldMethod() {
        return RANDOM.nextInt(0, 500) * 2 + 1;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int newMethod() {
        return RANDOM.nextInt(0, 1000) | 1;
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark              Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.newMethod  avgt  100  6.079 ± 0.137  ns/op
MyBenchmark.oldMethod  avgt  100  6.325 ± 0.009  ns/op
```

`oldMethod` can be improved slightly by using `<< 1` instead of `* 2`, but `newMethod` is still slightly faster.

Comment: `nextInt(1, 1_000) | 1` will not generate an even distribution. There is 1/999 chance of value 1, but 2/999 chance of all the other odd numbers. --- `nextInt(0, 1_001) & -2` will return both 0 and 1000, but question says *"1 (inclusive) to 1000 (exclusive)"*. --- For even distributions, and correct ranges, use `nextInt(0, 1_000) | 1` and `nextInt(2, 1_000) & -2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `2n + 1` approach is good. You can use streams and wrap it up in a helper method for ease of use if you like:

```
import java.util.Random;

public static IntStream randomOdds(int from, int upTo) {
    return new Random().ints(from/2, upTo/2).map(n -> 2*n + 1);
}
```

Usage:

```
randomOdds(1, 1000).limit(20).forEach(System.out::println);
```